# K6 return timeout connexion errors

Tags: timeout, http-proxy, k6, connexion

I tried a script k6 to test reset wiremock deployed on flexible engine environment but i received this error:

dial tcp 10.228.222.99:443: connectex: Une tentative de connexion a échoué car le parti connecté n’a pas répondu convenablement au-delà d’une certaine durée ou une connexion établie a échoué car l’hôte de connexion n’a pas répondu

```
import http from "k6/http";
import { check, sleep } from "k6";
import { SharedArray } from "k6/data";
import encoding from 'k6/encoding';
import { FormData } from 'https://jslib.k6.io/formdata/0.0.2/index.js';

const scenarioFile = open('../assets/sipp_scenarios/sc-receiveInviteAndAnswer-answerHangup.xml', 'b');
const file = open('../assets/medias/3min_compressed.wav', 'b');
const dataEnv = new SharedArray ("environment",function(){
    return JSON.parse(open("../config/settings.json")).environment; //return array
});
function GetErrorResults(ResultURL) {
 console.error("unexpected response! request: " + String(ResultURL.request.url) + " "
 + String(ResultURL.request.body) + " answer status: "
 + String(ResultURL.request.status) +" body:"
 + String(ResultURL.body));
}
function getEnv(){
    let len = dataEnv.length;
    for(let i=0; i<len;i++){
        if(`${__ENV.MY_ENV}` == dataEnv[i].NAME){
            return dataEnv[i];
        }
    }
}
export const options = {
    insecureSkipTLSVerify: true,
    scenarios: {
      reset_wiremock: {
             exec: 'reset_wiremock',
             executor: 'per-vu-iterations',
             vus: 1,
             iterations: 1,
             maxDuration: '50s',
             gracefulStop: '3s',

          }    }

};


export function reset_wiremock(){
    const url = getEnv().EXTERNAL_WIERMOCK_URL+ "/__admin/reset";
    //reset wiremock
    var response = http.post(url);
    if (!check(response, {
     'status is 200 for reset': r => r.status == 200
     })) {
     GetErrorResults(response)
     }else {
     console.info(`MOLKA`);
     };
    return response;
};

the cmd : HTTPS_PROXY=http://proxyparfil.......:8080  k6 run -e MY_ENV=integration k6-scripts/test.js
```